# El significado idiomático de la cal

Tags: modismos, significado

Encontré un modismo que me interesa (inventé un ejemplo):

> ¡Nos debemos ir! La policía va a cerrar esta lugar a cal y canto.
>
> *We gotta get out of here! The police are going to lock this place down.*

Mi pregunta:

**¿Podrían explicarme el significado de "cal" y su relación con el canto?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aquí no se habla de "cantar" en primera persona sino de un canto, que es un trozo de piedra y se refiere generalmente a la terminación de ésta: si es redonda o tallada.

> Cerrado a cal y canto

es una frase que viene de la españa antigua: cuando sellaban las puertas de una casa para que nadie entrara, las cerraban con piedras y una mezcla de cal; por eso cuando las **cerraban a cal y canto** ya era imposible acceder a ellas.

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Yo creía que 'la cal' hubiera significado una fruta. Wish I could upvote now.

Answer (score 0):

"cal y canto" o "calicanto" como bien dices es un modísmo.
Pero como tal, no puedes separar el significado y buscar la palabra "cal" separada de los otros componentes del modismo. (leer bien la definición de [modismo](http://dle.rae.es/modismo) vía RAE).

Si buscaste la palabra "cal" (separada) en la RAE, te sale la definición del producto químico que se usa en construcción (de viviendas).

Y te explican ahí mismo el modismo que estás dando de ejemplo aquí.
No tiene relación "cal" con "cantando" (de cantar).
El "canto" no viene de cantar siempre. Hay varios significados para "canto".
Lee [canto(2)](http://dle.rae.es/canto) en la RAE.

Saludos